# Write a java program to retrieve the player details based on the player id from the array of player objects

Tags: java

this is my code:

```
public class Player

    2 public class PlayerUtility {
  
    4   public Player findPlayerDetailsById(Player[] arr, int playerIdToSearch){
    
    7 ..
          
   18 return null;   
    2 public class Main {
    3   public static void main(String[] args) {
   ...
        
   12       PlayerUtility obj=new PlayerUtility();
        ..
   18           System.out.println(obj.findPlayerDetailsById(pObj,id));
        
   21   if(obj.findPlayerDetailsById(pObj,id)==null)
   22   {
   23       System.out.println("No player found");
```

It's giving the outputs as expected according to the test cases but there's one failed test case Fail 1 -
Check the return type of findPlayerDetailsById method in PlayerUtility class(or)the findPlayerDetailsById method returns the null value
what should i return instead?

Comment: returning in main with return type void? This wouldn't even compiler. Also, return the value but where?

Comment: Also, to call `findPlayerDetailsById` you need to create an object of `Class PlayerUtility` and call the method using that obj

Answer (score 0):

First thing please remove return statement from main because main is of void type.

Second check whether array variable  Obj is even initialized or not(or even you need to use Obj value which is not required)or you only need arr variable to complete operation

Third implement getPlayerName and getPhoneNumber method before calling them.

Fourth check this statement pObj.setPlayerId(id) it's incorrect because you cannot call method without using array index which will refer to an object.

Remove these basic error and edit problem with new issue you are facing if their is any

Comment: Yes thank you , i did some changes and it's working fine now but they dont want me to return null by the findPlayerDetailsById method what can be an alternative?

Comment: You need to return Player Object from findPlayerDetailsById method that is required to fetch player by Id.

Answer (score 0):

update:
i was able to get rid of the last error by returning the array and not an empty object.
Thank you for all the help!